# How to read out a double negation in propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-logic

How would one verbally say ~~R where R = my program is correct? The tildes are negation symbols. I'm not sure if it just cancels out and comes out as 'my program is correct' or if it's something else.

Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way to pronounce "~" is as "not", so one could pronounce that as "not not R".

But frankly, pronouncing complex logic formulas can be ugly, and often it's better to just write it on a whiteboard or piece of paper and point.

Yes, ~~R is equivalent to R.

Answer (score 22):

The answer by @D.W. is valid in [classical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_logic) logic, however if you are on the [intuitionistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic) side, then you can't eliminate double negation (~~).

I'd read the formula as 'It is *not* true that my program is *not* correct'.

Comment: Or, in a more natural English way, "my program is not incorrect"

Comment: @jmite your statement misses another negation. it should say "[it's NOT the case that] my program is NOT correct]"

Comment: +1 for going beyond classical/binary. the world is definitely not just true and false.

Comment: @Mzn the second negation is implicit in the word "incorrect", which means "not correct".

Comment: @jmite You are not not right, I misread what you wrote. Thanks for the heads up...

Comment: @jmite You're right, it's way better English, but I was trying to be "mechanical". Is there an approach to translating a sentence like this "~~(This is a dog)"? I mean sufficiently different from "it's not [true]/[the case] that ..."

Comment: @Mzn, if I'm not mistaken, you are misinterpreting Intuitionist logic: it does not posit a third truth value, but rather defers *assigning* one of two truth values until proof.

Comment: @brianpck thanks for your comment. Well I did mention binary to contrast with intuitionistic logic. In a binary system, not not (false) definitely means true (end of discussion). But in intuitionistic logic it's not like that. it's like what you said, i need to prove truth rather than "it's not the case that false" or "~~".
Although I didn't say intuition logic is ternary, why isn't it? Doesn't the fact that ~~R not necessarily = R means that ~~R is a third state?

Comment: @Mzn, I don't know enough about intuitionist logic to answer your question, but here's one thing that occurred to me: if we wish to call "~~R" a third state (rather than the *absence* of a state), then we are likewise forced to call ~~~R a *fourth* state, ~~~~R a 5th, etc. *ad infinitum*.

Comment: @brianpck, nice idea! so it's better not to think of ~~R as a state on it's own... Thanks for the discussion :)

Comment: @Mzn think of implication $x ==> y$ as the process "given a proof of $x$, I can produce a proof of $y$". Then `~x` is just the process "given a proof of x, I can find  contradiction; ie prove false", since `~x = (x ==> false)`. Anyhow  using the aforementioned interpretations,  we have `R ==> ~(~R)` (nifty exercise) but do not have `~(~R) ==> R`. Hence they are not generally identical, but this does not mean there is a new state mucking about. We have many distinct propositions in the world and they do not introduce new states, so nothing new is happening. New interpretation means we lost an =

Comment: @MusaAl-hassy This is a nice way to explain it. In binary logic, which is very clear, ~~X definitely means X. Can you explain why it could be the case that: it's not the case that R is incorrect DOES NOT MEAN THAT R is correct. I'm thinking of logic here as we use it in programming languages. 0 and 1. I'm asking to learn more about the perspective on intuitionistic logic. Thanks!

Comment: If we're only using 0/1 and *ignoring* proofs, then by definition ~~x=x. However, when we *consider proofs* and then ~p is a function of the form `p ==> False` and so takes a proof of `p` and produces a proof of `False`, then we no longer have that process `~~p` and process `p` coincide.  So it depends on whether you care about proofs or not ---the former is intuitionistic and the latter classic 0/1.

Comment: @MusaAl-hassy  Intuitionistic logic is not only about proofs. It's more about which rules of inference one accepts. One can easily take intuitionistic rules of inference and add a rule which will allow double negation elimination (or incorporate the law of excluded middle and so on), i.e. one will get classical logic, based on proofs. D. van Dalen's Logic and Structure book contains an example of natural deduction system for classical logic.